# Reduce CPU usage of a running process: Unix Command

Tags: unix, resources

I was trying to find a UNIX/Linux command to limit memory and CPU usage once I realize that a process is consuming 90% or more. So basically a command to reduce usage on a process that is already running without restarting the process. Thank you.

Comment: This question doesn't belong to stackoverflow, I'd try serverfault. Also you can't just "reduce" CPU usage, you can only lower the priority of the process (-> keywords `nice` and `renice`).

Answer (score 2):

nice (built-in)
or
cpulimit http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: nice works when you are launching the process, you cannot nice an already running process.

Comment: You can. There is `renice` for that.

Comment: 23 May 2012, CPUlimit has moved to github https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit

Answer (score 2):

/usr/bin/ulimit or the shell builtin ulimit can be used when you launch the process to set resource limits.  Not after the process is running.  The nice command is run as the process owner BEFORE you run the image file.  Not after

renice is the command used after the process has already started.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to set a hard limit on CPU usage. But you can force a process to be *nicer* to other processes with the `renice` command

```
renice -n 10 -p PID
```

where `PID` is the process id of the process whose priority you want to reduce.

What this does is tell the OS scheduler to reduce the process's priority, i.e. other processes that want to run get more of the CPU. `man 1 renice` has the details.